# Why incompatible types?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, object, shared-libraries

I am trying to have `startForeground(int, id, notification)` in my service, but for that I need a notification parameter. For the last 3 hours I have been trying to create that notification, but it just won't work:

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Notification title")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("Notification text");
```

**Here is the error:**

[image]

I have tried removing and replacing all of my imports, but nothing works. How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `.build()` on your notification builder to get the notification:

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Notification title")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("Notification text") // <---- NotificationCompat.Builder
                .build(); // <--------
```

You were trying to assign a `NotificationCompat.Builder` to a `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer in 7 minutes. I have a question for `startForeground`. What is the ID for?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia It's a unique identifier for the notification

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: This is the same ID that is used [with `notify()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)). You use it to identify this `Notification`, in case you need to update its contents while the `Notification` is still outstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

you will see that there is a final .build() at the end of the chain. Then the Notification object is returned. That is, try:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Notification title")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Notification text")
            .build();
```

Comment: I have a question for `startForeground`. What is the purpose of int ID?